# Accessing different properties in a typescript union type

Tags: if-statement, typescript, object-properties

I'm creating a function that handles objects from the database. I have two different data structures where the same property has a different name. I can't change that, so I have to handle it in JavaScript.
The objects have other differences, but that's not important to this function.
I want to use the same function for two different types of objects. Here's sample code demonstrating my problem:

```
interface TypeA {
    itemName: string;
}

interface TypeB {
    itemTitle: string;
}

function getItemName(item: TypeA | TypeB): string {
    let name = '';

    if (item.hasOwnProperty('itemName')) {
        name = item.itemName;
    } else {
        name = item.itemTitle;
    }

    return name;
}
```

Of course, this code runs. But the IDE marks both the lines `name = item.itemName;` and `name = item.itemTitle;` as errors ("Property does not exist on type"), because both types do not have both properties.

So, what's the proper typescript way to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to create a User Defined Type Guard, then you can use an if statement and get the correct typing.

```
function isTypeA(value: TypeA | TypeB): value is TypeA {
    return value.hasOwnProperty('itemName');
}
```

Then you can get the typing much cleaner:

```
function getItemName(item: TypeA | TypeB): string {
    return isTypeA(item) ? item.itemName : item.itemTitle;
}
```

Check it out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20TypeA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20itemName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20TypeB%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20itemTitle%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getItemName(item%3A%20TypeA%20%7C%20TypeB)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20isTypeA(item)%20%3F%20item.itemName%20%3A%20item.itemTitle%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20isTypeA(value%3A%20TypeA%20%7C%20TypeB)%3A%20value%20is%20TypeA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20value.hasOwnProperty('itemName')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A).  Item is correctly cast to either TypeA or TypeB.

Comment: If either type is a class, alternatively you can rely on `instanceof`, to maintain the type safety. Example: `const prop = item instanceof Foo ? item.fooProp : item.barProp`

Answer (score 33):

I might be a little bit late, but you could give this a try inside your function:

```
if ('itemName' in item) {
    name = item.itemName;
} else {
    name = item.itemTitle;
}
```

Comment: This is certainly the quickest option! A User Defined Type Guard can be a bit overkill for a simple issue.

Comment: This will fail if `itemName` is something like `toString`, `valueOf`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

you can make a type assertion if you don't do this too often :

```
if (item.hasOwnProperty('itemName')) {
    name = (item as TypeA).itemName;
} else {
    name = (item as TypeB).itemTitle;
}
```

or

```
if (item.hasOwnProperty('itemName')) {
    name = (<TypeA>item).itemName;
} else {
    name = (<TypeB>item).itemTitle;
}
```

if you need to make this check more than once or twice, you'd better writing a type guard as @Daryl suggests.

Answer (score 5):

```
interface TypeA {
  a: string
}
interface TypeB {
  b: string
}

const testFunction = (x: TypeA | TypeB): string => {
  return (x as TypeA).a || (x as TypeB).b;
}

testFunction({ a: 'Hello' }); // 'Hello'
testFunction({ b: 'World' }); // 'World'
```

Answer (score 1):

Intellij accepts this syntax:

```
function getItemName(item: TypeA): string;
function getItemName(item: TypeB): string;
function getItemName(item): string {
    return item.hasOwnProperty('itemName') ? item.itemName : item.itemTitle;
}
```

the official way according to the typescript docs is this:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

I won't complicate things. If you're really sure that your object has either the one or the other property, a `name = item['itemName'] || item['itemTitle']` or `name = item.hasOwnProperty('itemName') ? item['itemName'] : item['itemTitle']` would be sufficient.

Note that TypeScript usually stops complaining if you access properties using the bracket notation instead of the dot notation. I would suggest adding a comment, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [typeguards](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html):

```
interface TypeA {
    itemName: string;
}

interface TypeB {
    itemTitle: string;
}

function isTypeA(val: any): val is TypeA
{
    return val.hasOwnProperty('itemName');
}

function isTypeB(val: any): val is TypeB
{
    return val.hasOwnProperty('itemTitle');
}

function getItemName(item: TypeA | TypeB): string
{
    let name = '';

    if (isTypeA(item))
    {
        name = item.itemName;
    }
    else
    {
        name = item.itemTitle;
    }

    return name;
}
```