# union type not able to work within an isolated context

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following code:

```
if (event.hasOwnProperty('body')) {
  Context.request = JSON.parse(event.body) as T;
} else {
  Context.request = event;
}
```

where `event` is defined as:

```
private static event: aws.IGatewayEvent | ut.IGenericEvent;
```

The first definition has a "body" attribute, the second does not. Still I'd expect that my conditional statement should let Typescript see that the only case left -- aka, where the object implements the `aws.IGatewayEvent` interface -- and not give the error:

> Property 'body' does not exist on type 'IGenericEvent | IGatewayEvent'.

Comment: very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496154/accessing-different-properties-in-a-typescript-union-type

Comment: That's a useful link @artem but I still the same errors when I abstract the type checking to a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Property 'body' does not exist on type 'IGenericEvent | IGatewayEvent'.

Property checks do not form an automatic type guard in TypeScript. You will have to create a user defined type guard for now.

## More

- [User Defined Type Guard](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html)

Comment: Thanks! You're right setting up a user defined type guard did work. I think what @artem was pointing to me probably was the same solution but at first I missed it because I'd casually thought that the "as" operator was being used instead of the "is" operator which i'd not seen before. In any case, thanks for the help.