# Typescript one type or another only

Tags: typescript

I want to return an object as fetch response that can have one of the property (data or mes):

```
{ data: Data } | { mes: ErrMessage }
```

Problem is that typescript complains about this object, let's say props:

```
if (prop.mes) return // Property 'mes' does not exist on type '{ data: string; }'.
prop.data // Property 'data' does not exist on type '{ mes: string; }'.
```

Is there any alternative except (it's not convenient to define this big type in component every time):

```
{ data: Data, mes: false } | { mes: ErrMessage, data: false}
```

Typescript playground [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=30#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnAshAzighgc2gXii4OASwDtMoB6C-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-qfuuP6GAK-qAcBB6geBHCQVA0GwQKfLFD4KqoVk6FQMIWRAA).

```
type ErrMessage = string // some complex structure

const fetchAPI = <Body = any, Data = any>(link: string, body: Body): Promise<{ data: Data } | { mes: ErrMessage }> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      fetch(link, { body: JSON.stringify(body) })
      .then((raw) => raw.json())
      .then((res) => {
        resolve(res.err ? { mes: res.err } : { data: res })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        resolve({ mes: 'text' })
      })
  })
}

type Data = string // some complex structure
type MyReq = string // some complex structure
type MyRes = {data: Data } | {mes: ErrMessage}

const someLoader = async () => {
    const res = await fetchAPI<MyReq, MyRes>('reader', 'body')
    return {res}
}

const componentThatGetProp = (prop: MyRes ) => {
    // error handler
    if (prop.mes) return // Property 'mes' does not exist on type '{ data: string; }'.

    // do something
    prop.data // Property 'data' does not exist on type '{ mes: string; }'. 
}
```

Comment: @sinanspd i don't think so as it's a generic type, and as i know types can't be generics by themselfs.

Comment: deleted the comment after realizing that. My bad. It is not clean but it looks like you either need to do some type assertion -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496154/accessing-different-properties-in-a-typescript-union-type

or go undefined (it is actually recommend you use msg?: never rather then undef but yeah... not any better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (prop.mes) return
```

just try

```
if ('mes' in prop) return
```

one tries to *access* the property (which might not be there), the other *checks for it's existence*

Comment: This answer is simple and makes the example code's error go away: !

Answer (score 2):

The "right" type for TypeScript to use is

```
type MyRes = { data: Data, mes?: undefined} | { mes: ErrMessage, data?: undefined}
```

where the irrelevant properties in each member of the union are optional and have an `undefined` value, as opposed to a `false` value.  (Or you could use `never` instead of `undefined`, since optional properties always get `| undefined` added to them, and `never | undefined` is just `undefined`.)  That corresponds to what will actually happen if you check an irrelevant property: it will be missing.  [As of TypeScript 3.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants), the compiler treat the above type as a [discriminated union](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) and your errors will go away:

```
const componentThatGetProp = (prop: MyRes) => {
  // error handler
  if (prop.mes) return // okay
  // do something
  prop.data // okay
}
```

---

I agree that it would be a pain to manually turn a union type your existing `MyRes` into one where each union member contains all the keys from all the other union members.  Luckily you don't need to do this manually.  TypeScript's [conditional types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) let you programmatically manipulate a "regular" union into the discriminated form above.  Here's one way to do it, using a type alias called I'll call `ExclusifyUnion<T>` to indicate that it takes a union type `T` and turns it into a new union type where the compiler can tell that any value of that type must match one member of the union *exclusively*:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;

type ExclusifyUnion<T, K extends AllKeys<T> = AllKeys<T>> =
  T extends any ?
  (T & { [P in Exclude<K, keyof T>]?: never }) extends infer U ?
  { [Q in keyof U]: U[Q] } :
  never : never;
```

I can explain that if you want, but the sketch is this: `AllKeys<T>` returns all keys from a union `T`, so `AllKeys<{a: string} | {b: number}>` is `"a" | "b"`.  And `ExclusifyUnion<T>` takes each member of the union and intersects it with a type containing all the rest of the keys as optional properties of type `never`.  So `ExclusifyUnion<{a: string} | {b: number} | {c: boolean}>` will end up looking like `{a: string, b?: never, c?: never} | {b: number, a?: never, c?: never} | {c: boolean, a?: never, b?: never}`.  Here's what it does to `MyRes`:

```
type MyRes = ExclusifyUnion<{ data: Data } | { mes: ErrMessage }>
/*type MyRes = {
    data: string;
    mes?: undefined;
} | {
    mes: string;
    data?: undefined;
}*/
```

And this should scale up easily even if `MyRes` has more union members with more properties.

---

Okay, hope that gives you a path forward.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA0hEBnAPAFQHxQLxSZQQAewEAdgCapQCGFIUA-FANYoD2AZoVAFxQKEAG4QATgG4AUNNCQoAURIBjOAFdUAS24gAqhS2cKWADRRExMpRqwEyNFlwF4SFBhzPpUPqXLVaBiZmbygACiIAMigAbygAbQAFKC0KJVUNKgh0RHMOEB5CbABdZkFhMXEoAF8ASit-W1TuCSg9FlC4+IBFFLT8wr1iwT0e4pqBUIrW8tEJGWkAemWV1bX11dl5aEVxcQBZCFRUOgBzaAJUYHFU06hlqFROAFtoFRewOFJH6-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-OsnwHibTgqhy6gvnEUIdHCUrODAX0pXqGLNRAzg2DoEBQgeKhOFAtzoVuUJ2s61jCQeAahrUoA)