# Typescript: How to accept 2 different types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a method `getRoute` that takes a `video`.  The `video` is either of `LiveVideo` type or `RecordedVideo` type.  My problem is that `getLiveID` field is only in `LiveVideo` so I am getting the editor issue `property` getLiveID `does not exist on type RecordedVideo`.  What is the way around this?  I want to use 1 method to handle both and handle the conditional logic within.

```
getRoute(video: LiveVideo | RecordedVideo) {
   if (video.getLiveID) {

     ///
   } else {
      ///
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check which type you have using `in`. For example:

```
getRoute(video: LiveVideo | RecordedVideo) {
   if ("getLiveId" in video) {
     // treat as LiveVideo
   } else {
     // as RecordedVideo
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
getRoute(video: LiveVideo | RecordedVideo) {
  if (video instanceof LiveVideo) {
    // "video" is of type LiveVideo here...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Gives a typescript error `LiveVideo only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Answer (score 1):

```
type LiveVideo = {
    getLiveID: Function,
    id: string
}

type RecordedVideo = {
    id: string
}

function getRoute(video: LiveVideo | RecordedVideo) {
    if ((video as LiveVideo)?.getLiveID) {

        ///
    } else {
        ///
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party!

There's also this method you can use, just found it on another so question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70728314/15832658

I like it because it's clean and you know which type you're referring to

Also you can check other answers of that thread, there are different nice ways to do it