# Conditional type based on one property

Tags: typescript

When `actions` is defined in the object, I want type `C` to be `B`, when it's not defined, I want type `C` to be `A`, how to implement such type/interface?

```
interface A {
  label: string
  prop: string
}

interface B {
  label?: string
  actions: string[]
}

// Pseudocode
type C = actions ? B : A

const c1: C = { //  type A
  label: 'c1',
  prop: 'c1',
}

const c2: C = { //  type B
  label: 'c2',
  actions: ['c2'],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a type parameter on `C` so that it knows what type its dealing with, which for the assignments shown makes `C` fairly pointless (just use `A` or `B`). You also can't infer type arguments in simple assignments like those.

You can with functions, though, so if you're really writing a function and just simplified it for the question (or you're happy to have a pass-through function), you can do this:

```typescript
type C<T> = T extends { actions: string[] } ? B : A;

function example<T>(data: T): C<T> {
    return data as C<T>;
}

const c1 = example({
    label: "c1",
    prop: "c1",
});
console.log(c1);
//          ^? const c1: A

const c2 = example({
    label: "c2",
    actions: ["c2"],
});
console.log(c2);
//          ^? const c2: B
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=15&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QGzgCMJ8B+ALmQGcwpQBzAbhzwAcoB7Nq2+kZlgC+WLKEixEKAEKZWuQiXK86jFnmSIwwTiGqUaqgQG0AuixFYwATzYoAwgB4AKgD5kAXmTPkEAB6QIAAm1JiaCNq61Cr8DGbIQshkyLJUqCxYMACuIBE6IL5+cAC2bPgQLq4AFEFwYHBUzgCUVE5uchpQEGBZUAW19Zqhba4WoghRYMgIAIyehSVlEFXYGoqkVABEs5sANPLIHNxbO-tCTSwTepzlAHT4nAxVsxdYAPRvGl-IAHpk45NpgAmeb+RblFYHdb4E5AvYHLT5aLIYzbOGmM6vK7UG4Qe6PZ5A14fb4aP5AA)

Comment: Wow, thanks! Where is `//          ^? const c1: A` this feature documented? It works in vscode too.

Comment: @WenfangDu - It's a [twoslash query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#handbook-14). Currently only supported in the Playground, but [there's a suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52839) to add support for it to what editors get from TypeScript (though there's some question whether TypeScript itself needs to change anything there; it already supports type inlays, so the information is available to the editor if it asks for it).

Comment: @WenfangDu *"It works in vscode too"* Really? It doesn't for me (yet). Maybe I'm behind, what version are you on? I'm on 1.75.1.

Comment: That's strange, mine is the same version, [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmKWD.png).

Comment: @WenfangDu - Thanks for the screenshot. Maybe you have some extension I don't? (I just upgraded to v1.76.0 and still don't have twoslash queries.)

Comment: Disabling [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar) removed that feature.

Comment: Nice debugging @WenfangDu! :-)

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that I also [disabled the vscode builtin typescript plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sL26.png), and used [this TS server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.vscode-typescript-vue-plugin) exclusively for all TS files following [this guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode).

Comment: The real use case is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp5vM.png), dividing `Column` into two separate types, so I'm not sure if a function can be used here.

Comment: @WenfangDu - It depends on why you want to split it, and what you mean by two separate types. Completely separate, or one extending the other, or...?

Comment: Sorry for my description, it's more like `type Column = actions ? ColumnB: ColumnA`, here's the [data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv2BH.png), you will understand by seeing this.

Comment: Looks like `Column` is just `A | B`?

Comment: I initially thought `type Column = A | B` would suffice, but when accessing `actions` on a column, TS throws `actions` doesn't exist on `A` :(.

Comment: @WenfangDu - That's normal, since it doesn't exist on all types in the union. So you have to use a type guard to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of the particular column you're working with (in this case, perhaps with [an `in` guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing)). See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496154/accessing-different-properties-in-a-typescript-union-type) (and the linked docs).

Comment: Thank you! That was incredibly helpful, I ended up using [`StrictUnion`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65805753/7881859) to implement [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NzLK.png), and the _"`actions` doesn't exist on `A`"_ issue went away.