Typescript Union type with intersection errors
I'm brushing up on my typescript and I have data that can be two different types of person which makes up part of a final object:
Note this is just an example mock-up to represent what I'm trying to achieve rather than the code I'm using.
type Person = {
  Name: string;
  Fullname: string;
  Age: number;
} | {
  Name: string;
  Surname: string;
  Age: string;
}

type finalObject = Person & {
  someField: string;
}

Then in my function I'm doing:
function myFunction(params: finalObject){
  if(params.hasOwnProperty('surname'){
    return {
    Name: params.name
    Surname: params.surname; // <---- Does not exist on finalObject
    Age: params.age;
    someField: someField;
   }
  } else {
   return {
     Name: params.name,
     Age: params.age,
     Fullname: params.fullName, // <--- Does not exist on finalObject
     someField: someField
   }
  }
}

In vscode typescript throws the error above listed in the comments. What's the correct way to achieve this, essentially the Person type needs a structure that always includes name and age but will include either fullname or surname which forms part of the final object.

Thank you for this, I don't think so no, where they're talking about type guards that would work if I were combining person into finalObject.

TS is unable to type narrow via that hasOwnProperty call.  Change the if condition to if("surname" in params). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59200046/1086398 for more details. The other way is to declare a type guard but I think the in may work here without the extra legwork in declaring one.

Oh dear that was embarrassingly simple, thanks a lot, if you post an answer I'll mark it correct.

I think it would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/66522765/1086398, so I'll just leave this comment here instead for future ref :). Glad its working for you!

Yeah OK, thing is that doesn't show that hasOwnProperty causes the problem as there;s other answers there still using it.

Yes but only in the context of type guards, casting or overloading -- which all are valid ways of mitigating the issue with hasOwnProperty and therefore solving the larger problem. They'd work here as well. Albeit, a bit convoluted if in works for you, but  that question is a fairly comprehensive rundown of the options. There are legit reasons for forcing hasOwnProperty since behavior is not identical to in, so kind of depends on the use case. Some would argue the hasOwnProperty solution are stricter. But i'd say it doesnt matter a lot of the time.
